# What happens by calling HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() more than twice

Tags: java, http

Does the `HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()` method fetch the contents with connecting to the server each time, or save the contents in the memory first time and give it back again from the second time? I'm building a function that takes in an `HttpURLConnection` instance and judges if the contents satisfy some criteria to be processed by another function later. Thank you!

Comment: You could just try it you know.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's what I thought up first, but I couldn't think up the way before I finished writing up the question. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual answer is in [`HttpURLConnection#connect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29) which states

> If the `connect` method is called when the connection has already been
>   opened (indicated by the `connected` field having the value true), **the
>   call is ignored.**

If you haven't called `connect()`, `getInputStream()` will call it itself. If you have, it will just be ignored.

You can find the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java?av=f).

Comment: I found the code of `if already called return it` there. Thank you!